# Two look-ahead strings using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a simple regex that looks like the following:

```
var myRegex = /%(?!FOO%)([A-Za-z_]*)%/g;
```

What I'm trying to do is find any instance of between two literal `%` quotes that isn't `FOO`. So anything like `BAR`, `WHATEVER` etc would match.

My question is, what's the best way to extend this to look for multiple strings? Let's say I want to match anything that isn't `FOO` or `BAR`.

```
var myRegex = /%(?!(FOO|BAR)%)([A-Za-z_]*)%/g;
```

I tried the variant above, but that only seems to find the first match, `FOO`. How do I make it find both?

Comment: That one with the `FOO|BAR` works for me.

Comment: Are you missing global flag?

Comment: Nope have the global flag in, forgot to put it in post. Edited.

Comment: What is the real data? You may think it is `FOO` while it is `F00`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this : (*assuming this is what you wanna accomplish*)

**General way** (*w/ [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) support*)

```
(?<=%)(?!FOO|BAR)(\w+)(?=%)
```

**JavaScript way** (*w/o [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) support*)

```js
var str = '%FOO%HELLO%BAR%WORLD%';
var match = str.match(/%(?!FOO|BAR)(\w+)(?=%)/g).map(e => {
  return e.replace('%', '');
});
console.log(match);
```